# mysql_connect() not working from class

Tags: php, mysql

Just moved my site to new hosting.  On the new server mysql_connect() works fine if called without using classes or inside of the method but not from the _construct.  When connecting from the _construct the following error displays:
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)...my configuration defines the user not as root but as USERNAME and does provides a password.

**PHP 5.6, MySQL 5.5, Linux**

**Class File:**

```
function __construct(){
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'USERNAME';
    $dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
    $dbname = 'DATABASENAME';
    $this->urlAppPath = "http://www.myurl.com/CD/";        
    // connect to the database
    $this->db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . $SQL);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
}    
function validatePerson($personID) {
    $SQL = "SELECT *,COUNT(*) AS total FROM zen_customers WHERE customers_classware_id = '$personID'";
    $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Could not execute query 1 . ".$SQL." ".mysql_error()." & ". $dbhost ." ".$dbuser ." ".$dbpass." ".$dbname);    
}
```

**Call Method File:**

```
require_once('./clsCart.php');
$myclass = new clsCart();
$result2 = $myclass->validatePerson($personID);
```

**Note**
If I define and call the connection within the file that I have been trying to call the method...that is instead of calling the method it works.  If I define and call the connection within the method it works...but if I define and call the connection within the construct() it does not work...error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". This seems to be specific to some servers...regardless of using PHP 5.6 or lower & MySQL 5.6 or lower.

So, if I use :

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'USERNAME';
$dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
$dbname = 'DATABASENAME';

// connect to the database
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . $SQL);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

Outside of the class or within the method then it works...but, I should (as I have in the past) be able to connect within the construct().

Comment: A note:- please stop using `mysql_*` now, it's deprecated and removed. Start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statement` and upgrade your php version too

Comment: You are not connecting before running the query most likely. "If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() had been called with no arguments.".

Comment: @ficuscr is right. can you show us more info on the code? like the part where you call the method?

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated in PHP 5.5

Comment: Thank you. I understand that mysql_connect is depreciated, however, it should still work until we upgrade to php 7.0. Our production environment is still using PHP 5.6 while our development environment is working on upgrading to PHP 7.0. If you could please let me know if you have any ideas on why the production version is producing this error on this server, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Alive to Die  Using mysqli_connect still gives a connection error:
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 1044 Debugging error: Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'localhost' to database 'DATABASENAME'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be related to a server issue.  From the __contruct() only the Database default user information is being recognized. Everywhere else in the applications uses the User created for the database, but the construct will only connect when using the default database user on this server.  Other servers are not having this issue, such that any database user with all privileges work.

Comment: __contruct() is not related to server

Comment: @Prabhu Nandan Kumar your suggestion did not work so you clearly do not understand the problem.  The thread has been answered and the issue resolved.

Comment: Which thread gave you answer please let me know @Tiffany Fischer ?

Comment: @Prabhu Nandan Kumar This one...that was voted down...isn't that ironic?  It worked.

Comment: It is a solution because it solved the problem...your suggestion of using mysqli did not solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

You have to use [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). Please never use [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) it deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and onwards. If still you face issue please let us know.

Following code for mysqli_connect :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

**Definition and Usage**
The mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.

***Syntax***

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

**Parameter Description**

*port*  Optional. Specifies the port number to attempt to connect to the MySQL server.

*socket*    Optional. Specifies the socket or named pipe to be used.

Comment: This software runs fine with mysql_connect() on my local server and another server using PHP 5.6.  It is something specific to the two other servers that I am using that it is not working...why would it not work on some servers and not others?

Comment: Using mysqli_connect still gives a connection error: Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 1044 Debugging error: Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'localhost' to database 'DATABASENAME'

Comment: Please understand that this is many environments that it does work not just local and some that do not work.  Also, when I changed to mysqli that did not solve the issue.  Please be respectful.